# SenchaTouch2: How to determine whether the show event is fired because a view is actually shown

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

In a sencha touch 2 `Ext.navigation.View`, it is possible to `push()` and `pop()` other views in and out. Those other views fire events like `hide` and `show`.Sadly, those events are fired in this order when pushing: (note the bold ones)

1. initialize
2. **hide**
3. activate
4. show

and like this when popping:

1. deactivate
2. hide
3. **show**
4. remove
5. destroy

So relying on either `show` or `hide` event is not the best idea as both get fired in both situations.
I consider this a bug and something similar has already been [discussed](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?180885-BETA2-Show-and-Hide-events-when-pushing-and-popping-views-fire-unexpectedly). Nevertheless this behaviour is still present in the version I use (ST 2.0.1.1) and according to the explanation of @rdougan in the forum:

> The reason behind this is that when an item is removed from a card
>   layout, it may actually be shown somewhere else - or perhaps it is
>   changing to be floatable. So we must revert the item back to its
>   original visible state.

it won't be changed as well. So I was trying to find out which event is **really** happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution for this problem. Assuming one listens to the event inside the view, not a controller, you may use this litte snippet:

```
Ext.Array.contains(this.up('navigationview').getActiveItem().getXTypes().split('/'), this.xtype)
```

to check whether your view is actually shown (`true`) or hidden (`false`). Of course, you have to define your own [`xtype`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-cfg-xtype) config property on the views you are using to make that work. In my case, it is an `Ext.Panel`.

Comment: Is there a problem with comparing instances? e.g.:
this.up('navigationview').getActiveItem() === this